# Wierd URL Encoding/Decoding for non English Characters

Tags: url, encoding, character-encoding

How and why a non-English word is converted to weird characters like `پاکستان` to `Ù¾Ø§Ú©Ø³ØªØ§Ù†`, is there any way back to get `پاکستان` from `Ù¾Ø§Ú©Ø³ØªØ§Ù†`. It happens in browser shown code and received requests at server

**Background:**

I get lot of requests at my Non-English content (urdu) website with urls like

```
Ù¾Ø§Ú©Ø³ØªØ§Ù†
```

I tried to know what that means but search engines don't help. I tried things like

1. Decode this 'mystring'
2. What ecoding is this 'mystring'
3. I thought it might be corrupted/spam url, from this link
   [Weird characters in URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25222973/weird-characters-in-url/25510366)

**Problem explanation/example**

But when I **viewed** one my js file in **browser** (while having look on working js file). It is showing me same **wired characters** in browser, even at localhost

---

```
'pakistan': {'eng': 'Pakistan', 'ur': 'Ù¾Ø§Ú©Ø³ØªØ§Ù†'},

//But actually source code for above line is following
'pakistan': {'eng': 'Pakistan', 'ur': 'پاکستان'},
```

But in browser its showing me following for same line,

**My knowledge**

I only know about Encoding/Decoding, which seems unrelated here with best of my knowledge as?

`encodeURI` and `decodeURI` in JS or `quote` and `unquote` in python and same for other languages. But what they do for me is only

```
`پاکستان` to `%D9%BE%D8%A7%DA%A9%D8%B3%D8%AA%D8%A7%D9%86` and vise versa
```

**Why needed?**
I don't want to miss the requests received with those malformed urls, there must be some things to undo as all browsers chrome/firefox/edge showing those characters same, If their translation/conversion method and result is same then there should be some technique available to reverse it as well

Comment: To me, it seems that UTF-8 will be read as CP1252 (Windows default user-space encoding). Where, why, at which state this happens, it is difficult to say. Check headers about encoding. Check `charset`, etc.

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi thanks a lot, I have updated my `'content-type' => 'xx/yy;` to `'content-type' => 'xx/yy; charset=UTF-8`, hope now all urls and data with unicode characters should not be encoded any more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [Giacomo Catenazzi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2758823/giacomo-catenazzi) and then I be greatful to the following answer

[How to decode cp1252 string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23326531/how-to-decode-cp1252-string#answer-23327698)

A very custom and still imperfect solution to my problem.

This algo needs to be improved Only by experiment I came to know, this algo works as its not working for me when string is long or including `-` (hyphens)

So I made changes according to my requirement and its working fair enough, so that I could guess what the actual string was.

```
import re, itertools
from lxml.builder import unicode


def specific_my_required_processing(received_string):
    starting_characters_in_encoded_string_in_my_case = ['Ø', 'Ã', 'Ù', 'Ù', 'Ú']
    arr = received_string.split('-')
    res = []
    missed = []
    for string_item in arr:
        decoded_string = guess_decode_string_without_hyphens(string_item)
        if decoded_string and decoded_string[:1] not in starting_characters_in_encoded_string_in_my_case:
            res.append(decoded_string)
        else:
            missed.append({string_item: decoded_string})
    resulting_urdu_string = '-'.join(res)
    print('\n\nResult', resulting_urdu_string)
    print('\nCould not be decoded', missed)


def guess_decode_string_without_hyphens(s):
    encodings = ['cp1251', 'cp1252', 'utf8']
    for steps in range(2, 10, 2):
        for encs in itertools.product(encodings, repeat=steps):
            r = s
            try:
                for enc in encs:
                    r = r.encode(enc) if isinstance(r, unicode) else r.decode(enc)
            except (UnicodeEncodeError, UnicodeDecodeError) as e:
                continue
            if re.match(u'^[\w\sа-яА-Я]+$', r):
                res = str(r)
                print('Encoding => ', encs, ' Conversion =   ' + s + '       =>        ' + res)
                return res


sample_encoded_string = 'Ø§Ø³Ù„Ø§Ù…-Ø¢Ø¨Ø§Ø¯-ÛØ§Ø¦ÛŒÚ©ÙˆØ±Ù¹-Ø§ÛŒ-ÙˆÛŒ-Ø§ÛŒÙ…-Ù‚Ø§Ù†ÙˆÙ†-Ø³Ø§Ø²ÛŒ-Ú©Ø§Ù„Ø¹Ø¯Ù…-Ù‚Ø±Ø§Ø±-Ø¯ÛŒÙ†Û’-Ú©ÛŒ-Ø¯Ø±Ø®ÙˆØ§Ø³Øª-Ù†Ø§Ù…Ú©Ù…Ù„-Ù‚Ø±Ø§Ø±'
specific_my_required_processing(sample_encoded_string)
```